# Meteor Slides as header only for homepage and Use featured image of each page as header for respective pages

Tags: plugins, post-thumbnails, headers

I am using meteor-slides plugin to make header as a slideshow. I am using twenty-eleven theme. Now i need to make this slideshow for my homepage only and featured images of other pages as headers for the respective pages. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got answer for it. I have changed the code to add meteor slides plugin in functions.php to show the slideshow just in the homepage.

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) {
    if ( function_exists( 'meteor_slideshow' ) ) { 
             meteor_slideshow(); 
        }
} ?>
```

After that i used a plug called [WP display header](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-display-header/) to set header image for each page

Comment: But how does that hook the slider into the header from your functions file when there's no header hook in the code?

Answer (score 0):

In your `header.php` check if you are an the front page:

```
if ( is_front_page() or is_home() )
{
    # your slider code here
}
else
{
    # your regular code
}
```

The front page is the top page, eg. `http://example.com/`. The home page is the page for your blog posts. That can be the same as your front page or a custom page like `http://example.com/news/`. See *Settings/Reading* in WP admin.

Comment: But how does that display the featured image as the header image on any page or post?

Comment: @BradDalton By putting the regular featured image code into the `else` block?